# Installing log4net multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, log4net

I have 3 projects in my solution, and those 3 projects include a separate Infrastructure project in which I have log4net installed and configured.

But the problem is I also have to install log4net in those 3 projects. 
Is it possible to only install it in Infrastructure project and not in the others? Or I have to install it everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

log4net must be installed in any project where you directly reference one of the log4net components. If you completely encapsulate the log4net functionality within the infrastructure project and then make calls to your own logging methods in that project then you won't need to install in the other 3 projects.

Comment: Where should the log4net app.config be located ?

Comment: @JesonMartajaya that is a very interesting question, did you manage to find out?

Comment: yes @DanielV. Here is the answer. You can store the config in a file, then have the `AssemblyInfo.cs`of the project specify it. Example: `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true, ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]`